# RSpec3.3 で it を 一行で記述する方法

Tags: ruby, rspec

`rspec 3.3` を使いテストを書いていたのですが、シンプルなテストだったので

```
it "condition1" do
  expect{foo[:hoge}.eq 1
end
it "condition2" do
  expect{foo[:moge}.eq 2
end
```

をそれぞれ一行で

```
it "condition1"{ expect{foo[:hoge}.eq 1 }
it "condition2"{ expect{foo[:moge}.eq 2 }
```

と書いた所

```
syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

のエラーになってしまいました。`do ~ end` と `{ ~ }` は等価だと思っていたのですがRSpecでは違うのでしょうか？

何かRSpecのオプションなどによって一行での記述を行えるようにすることはできますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rubyの仕様で、メソッドに引数と中括弧のブロックを同時に渡す場合はメソッドを丸括弧で囲む必要があります。
他にも同じようなパターンを下にまとめてみました。

```ruby
# 引数あり、丸括弧なし、中括弧ブロックあり => NG
irb(main):001:0> puts 'x' { 'y' }
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting end-of-input
puts 'x' { 'y' }
          ^

# 引数あり、丸括弧あり、中括弧ブロックあり => OK
irb(main):002:0> puts('x') { 'y' }
x
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts { 'y' }

# 引数なし、丸括弧あり、中括弧ブロックあり => OK
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> puts() { 'y' }

=> nil

# ハッシュが引数（中括弧あり）、丸括弧なし => NG
irb(main):005:0> puts { a: 1 }
SyntaxError: (irb):5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
puts { a: 1 }
         ^

# ハッシュが引数（中括弧あり）、丸括弧あり => OK
irb(main):006:0> puts({ a: 1 })
{:a=>1}
=> nil

# ハッシュが引数（中括弧あり）、丸括弧あり => OK
irb(main):006:0> puts({ a: 1 })
{:a=>1}
=> nil

# ハッシュが引数（中括弧なし）、丸括弧あり => OK
irb(main):007:0> puts(a: 1)
{:a=>1}
=> nil

# ハッシュが引数（中括弧なし）、丸括弧なし => OK
irb(main):008:0> puts a: 1
{:a=>1}
=> nil
```

ただ、いずれにしても元のRSpecの構文が少しおかしいです。正しくはこうなります。

```
it("condition1"){ expect(foo[:hoge]).to eq 1 }
it("condition2"){ expect(foo[:moge]).to eq 2 }
```

また、上のコードでもかまいませんが、itを一行で書きたいときはsubjectを使うこともよくあります。

```
describe 'foo' do
  subject { foo[key] }
  context 'with hoge' do
    let(:key) { :hoge }
    it { is_expected.to eq 1 }
  end
  context 'with moge' do
    let(:key) { :moge }
    it { is_expected.to eq 2 }
  end
end
```

テストコードが大きくなってくると、このようにしてテストコードのDRYさを求めた方が保守性が上がることもあります。

詳しくは以前書いたこちらのQiita記事を参照してください。

[subject を使ってテスト対象のオブジェクトを1箇所にまとめる](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/42193d066bd61c740612#subject-%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E5%AF%BE%E8%B1%A1%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%921%E7%AE%87%E6%89%80%E3%81%AB%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B)

Answer (score 2):

RSpec 固有の話ではなく、Ruby の文法の問題です。
次のように書けばよいです。

```
it("condition1"){ expect(foo[:hoge]).to eq 1 }
```

Ruby のリファレンスマニュアル http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/doc/spec=2fcall.html#block に記述があります。

> { ... } の方が do ... end ブロックよりも強く結合します